# Excel VBA GetObject() "Filename or class name not found during Automation operation"

Tags: excel, vba

I have "Main" folder which contains Main.xlsm and "readings" folder. Folder "readings" contains a file named Book1.xlsx. It only opens and closes the workbook for experiment with GetObject() function.
[Folder "Main" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXv6.png)
and
[Folder "readings" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilDWQ.png).
I am trying to open an existing workbook with vba GetObject() function by pressing a UserForm CommandButton, but receive an error (432)[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCSfk.png).

Here is code that I use:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyWB As Workbook
    Set MyWB = GetObject(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\readings\Book1.xlsx")
    MyWB.Close
    Set MyWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Later added [1hr]**: (P.S. I know about Workbooks.Open() method, but want to solve why GetObject() is not working)

**Later Added [2 hr]**: I tried on another computer and it worked, now I have to find out what is wrong with my system that prevents it to work.

**Later Added [06.02, evening]**: Repairing Office did not help, Full Office Uninstall and Reinstall also did not help, I am stuck

Please help to resolve why it is happening.
(Excel 2016, Windows 10 Pro 64bit)

Comment: You may try- `Workbooks.Open()` method.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I forgot to mention that I do not want to use Workbooks.Open() method because I found a suggestion from johnywhy on the MRexcel forum that GetObject() is a best solution when I want program to do everything in background.

Comment: So far I know `GetObject()` method works on already running application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function

Comment: I mean that I want to exactly understand why GetObject() does not work in my case.

Comment: Do you have space in folder name in which thisworkbook is located? Or are you working on thisworkbook which is not saved yet?

Comment: @Harun24HR Ou, ok, I found this advice here "https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-opening-workbooks-without-showing.304545/post-5747995". He also later mentions the CreateObject, but I am not sure should they be together with GetObject or not somehow.

Comment: And to the second question Folder "Main" is on the C drive. In the "Main" folder there is my "Main.xlsm" file and folder "readings". And in the "readings" folder there is only a file named "Book1.xlsx". So in total the path of Main.xlsm is: "C:\Main\Main.xlsm". And the path of Book1.xlsx is: "C:\Main\readings\Book1.xlsx". So there is no a single space in the both whole paths.

Comment: @Harun24HR, moment ago I tried it on another PC, and it worked but I do not understand why it does not work on my PC

Comment: What is result for `ThisWorkbook.Path`?

Comment: @Harun24HR, Thank you for replies, just a moment ago it was solved such easily that I could not think of it, (ThisWorkbook.Path = C:\Main)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Harun24HR for replies!

But finally, the reason was in - **I had to run Excel as Administrator**, I dont know why, because I tried on other computers and did not use Administrator and it worked, strange, but for my system the reason is this